"package crypto/ecdh is not in std" when using gccgo
I'm trying to compile a program written in Go. With Go standard compiler everything work and the program is generated normally.
But when I switch to gccgo compiler, errors like this appears:
$ go build -x -compiler gccgo
WORK=/tmp/go-build582779103
/home/user/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/crypto@v0.22.0/curve25519/curve25519_go120.go:9:8: package crypto/ecdh is not in std (/usr/lib/go-1.22/src/crypto/ecdh)


Strangely, the directory  exists and has the needed .go files:
$ ls /usr/lib/go-1.22/src/crypto/ecdh
 ecdh.go  ecdh_test.go  nist.go  x25519.go

This problem happens with more complex Go projects, with simple ones (for example, few dependencies) I can compile normally with gccgo.
My Go variables:
$ go env
GO111MODULE=''
GOARCH='amd64'
GOBIN=''
GOCACHE='/home/me/.cache/go-build'
GOENV='/home/me/.config/go/env'
GOEXE=''
GOEXPERIMENT=''
GOFLAGS=''
GOHOSTARCH='amd64'
GOHOSTOS='linux'
GOINSECURE=''
GOMODCACHE='/home/me/go/pkg/mod'
GONOPROXY=''
GONOSUMDB=''
GOOS='linux'
GOPATH='/home/me/go'
GOPRIVATE=''
GOPROXY='https://proxy.golang.org,direct'
GOROOT='/usr/lib/go-1.22'
GOSUMDB='sum.golang.org'
GOTMPDIR=''
GOTOOLCHAIN='auto'
GOTOOLDIR='/usr/lib/go-1.22/pkg/tool/linux_amd64'
GOVCS=''
GOVERSION='go1.22.4'
GCCGO='/usr/bin/gccgo'
GOAMD64='v1'
AR='ar'
CC='gcc'
CXX='g++'
CGO_ENABLED='1'
GOMOD='/dev/shm/glider/go.mod'
GOWORK=''
CGO_CFLAGS='-O2 -g'
CGO_CPPFLAGS=''
CGO_CXXFLAGS='-O2 -g'
CGO_FFLAGS='-O2 -g'
CGO_LDFLAGS='-O2 -g'
PKG_CONFIG='pkg-config'
GOGCCFLAGS='-fPIC -m64 -pthread -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -ffile-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build4284307836=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches'

My gccgo version is 13.3.0
PS.: The program I'm trying to compile with help of gcc is Glider.

The GCC 12 and 13 releases include a complete implementation of the Go 1.18 standard library. However, GCC does not yet include support for generics.

my code was working well one minute later, this error shows up and it is not going despite the various effort to fix it!

Why using gccgo?

@Christoph I was trying to intercept bind() and connect() in the program with shared/dynamic libraries, with executables compiled by Go, LD_PRELOAD doesn't work even with a dynamic Go executables, neither if I hack the ELF header in the executable nor inserting the library in the process PID with additional tools. With executables generated by gccgo, I can intercept bind() and connect () without any problem. However only few simple programs compile with gccgo in my host, that's why I asked here. Thanks.

@rocka2q Generics? Maybe it is the point. Thanks.
